# react-stockcharts: Rendering in small width (< 150px) breaks the chat

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, charts

With the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'date' of undefined
at xAccessor (CustomChart.js?1fd6:41)
at filterData (evaluator.js?801f:101)
at calculateState (ChartCanvas.js?8b5c:246)
at resetChart (ChartCanvas.js?8b5c:103)
at ProxyComponent.componentWillMount (ChartCanvas.js?8b5c:1057)
at ProxyComponent.wrappedMethod (react-hot-loader.development.js?c2cb:506)
at callComponentWillMount (react-dom.development.js?61bb:6860)
at mountClassInstance (react-dom.development.js?61bb:6956)
at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js?61bb:8325)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js?61bb:8966)
```

I tried with both `fitDimention` and `fitWidth`. My dataset only contains 10 points x-axis.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ah.. it wasn't really a bug. I forgot to remove the margins and I think they are calculated fiercely! Removing the margin did the trick.